# Public IP Address Authentication required

Tags: python, authentication, server, ip

I'm running a simple python web server on my computer. When I access it through Chrome with the url `http://localhost` it works fine, but if instead I use my public ip address `http://<my_address>`, I get this popup:

[image: Authentication Required]

First of all, I should be able to use my public ip address and "localhost" basically interchangeably... correct?

Second, what is this authentication? Where can I find the username and password? I tried the credentials for my modem/router... didn't work.

Third, how do I get rid of this authentication?

Comment: I think this is coming from your webserver configuration. Check httpd.conf or .htaccess.

Comment: What web server is this? Just a Python listener on Port 80? You cannot use `localhost` and `public IP` interchangeably in many cases. How did you find the IP, and are you sure it is your public IP (to me it looks like `192.168.x.y`)?

Comment: The python code is:
`from http.server import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler as Handler
from socketserver import TCPServer
port = 80
httpd = TCPServer(('', port), Handler)
httpd.serve_forever()`

And the address is this type: https://www.ipchicken.com/

Comment: If I can't use my ip address, is there any way for me to access that server from a different machine? Or does that require more infrastructure?